# XDebug doesn't work with proxies

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am using xampp for php development and eclipse indigo with PDT 3.0 for debugging purpose.

I used curl functions for my web operations wherein i could specify my proxy settings using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "host:port");
```

I am trying to use `get_meta_tags()` of php to fetch all the meta tags but the proxy is refusing connection. I haven't got an idea how to go about this. I have configured XDebug to run without proxy. I simply enabled **DBGp Proxy Support** and entered the proxy address in the **host:port** format. I am using the existing IDE Key i.e. **ECLIPSE_DBGP** in my php.ini file.

When i launch the debug mode it never finishes the launch. It gets stuck at 24%. As soon as i removed disabled **DBGp Proxy Support** , my debugger launched.

My php.ini config for XDebug looks as follows:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "E:\others\xampp-win32-1.7.7-VC9\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9876
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.idekey = "ECLIPSE_DBGP"
```

Am i missing anything ? Do i need to specify something more ? In Eclipse or the .ini file ?
Please let me know.

Thanks,
Adithya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.It looks like port 9000 which is be default used for debugging was in use. I change the port and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The debug proxy setting is for a specific "xDebug Proxy" program, not a web type proxy to use over the internet.

In order to use it, you will need to set up something like pydbgpproxy

See this link http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-multiple-users.html